# Extract day from datetime column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, reshape

I have a dataset with a DateTime column "LastUdated". It contains data updated every 30 minutes between 8-4 every day. I would like to extract singular data from this column (like average occupancy) to perform a regression model. [dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3iPl.png)

Comment: What is your question? Please read [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

If your column is already using datetime format, you just need to use:

```py
df['your_column'].dt.day          # to get day of the month
df['your_column'].dt.dayofweek    # to get day of the week
```